# Excel: Count If statement ignore hidden rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that takes on the values "Y" or "N". How do I count how many values in the column are "Y" and the rows are not hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(C7:C13,ROW(C7:C13)-MIN(ROW(C7:C13)),,1)), – -(C7:C13=B2))
```

from [Here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/06/07/formula-forensics-023/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with

`=COUNTIF(A:A,"Yes")` or `=COUNTIF(A:A,"No")` ?

Comment: Yes but this will include hidden rows.